# Count Year from Start_Date till End_Date

Tags: excel, vba, date, count

Count Year from Start_Date till End_Date based and write "Text Year 1", "Year 2" and so on

I'm trying to get the count of Years based on the Start Date and End Dates for every completion of 12 months.
Example: IF the start date is 26/11/2019 and the End date is 25/06/2019 it should give "Year1" till the end date complete 12 months and from the next date till completion of 12 months it should give "Year2" and so on.
Below are the sample data

```
Start_Date   End_Date       Text to Appear    Notes
26/12/2019   25/06/2020     Year-1            Start of First Year
26/06/2020   25/12/2020     Year-1            Completion of 12 months
26/12/2020   25/06/2021     Year-2            Start of Second Year
26/06/2021   25/12/2022     Year-2            Completion of 12 months
26/12/2022   25/06/2022     Year-3            Start of Second Year
26/06/2022   25/12/2023     Year-3            Completion of 12 months
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the result in column E you want will be always double ? so the start row value in column E will always "Year 1", then the next row will "Year 1" again. So the pattern from the top row to down : `Year 1, Year 1, Year 2, Year 2 ---> Year N, Year N`. So here there is no need a calculation based on column "start date" and column "end date". Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Dear Karma, thank you for visiting my post, the dates in column will change some times it wil be monthly some times it will be quarterly, what im looking is based on the start date till twelve months it should show Year1 and after completion of 12 months when the next year start, it should show Year 2.

Comment: Aleem, do you mean something like this ? The start date will be always in the first row column C ---> what I mean is that the rows in column C is already sorted in ascending. So it will never happen that the value in column C (starts from the first row) something like this : `26-06-29, 26-06-25, 26-12-20, 26-12-28, 26-12-05` ---> as this is not sorted either in ascending or descending. If it's sorted ascending, then column C first row value will always be the earliest date of the data and the last row will always be the latest date of the data. (continue)

Comment: The data in the image is a fixed pattern where from startdate to enddate it always take two rows to complete 12 months. It will be a different case if it's not a fixed pattern. Which it may vary to something like this ---> row1 start:03-04-19 end:10-08-19, row2 start:11-08-19 end:03-10-19, row3 start:04-10-19 end:02-04-20 ---> with the data like this, for a startdate 03-04-19 to complete 12 months will take three rows. So the result in column E : Year 1, Year 1, Year 1. And depend on the data, the next result can be Year 2, Year 2, Year 2, Year 2, Year 3, Year 3, and so on.

Comment: Dear Karma, yes your last comment is correct, the date in column C will have start date however if it is half year frequency it will take two rows to complete year, if it is quarterly then 4 rows to complete one year or if it is monthly then 12 rows to complete one year then next year will start.

Comment: Aleem, whether it's half/quarter/monthly/etc, will the start of the year be always 26-12 (Dec 26 year X) ? and to complete 12 months, the end be always 25-12 (Dec 25 year X+1) ? If yes, I think I can try to make the code because it has a consistent pattern no matter how many rows it needs to complete 12 months.

Comment: Dear Karma, Yes for this project the start date alwasy be 26-12 (Dec 26 yearX).

Comment: Aleem, what about the date which complete the 12 months ? will it always be Dec 25 year X+1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this :

```
Sub test()
Set Start = Range("A2")
Set rngEnd = Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Set rngFind = rngEnd.Offset(0, 20)
rngFind.Value = "=text(RC[-20],""dd-mmm"")"
rngFind.Copy
rngFind.PasteSpecial (xlValues)
Start.Select

n = Application.CountIf(rngFind, "25-Dec")
Set c = rngFind.Find("25-Dec", lookat:=xlWhole)
For i = 1 To n

Range(Start.Offset(0, 2), c.Offset(0, -19)).Value = "Year " & i
Set Start = c.Offset(1, -21)
Set c = rngFind.FindNext(c)
Next i

rngFind.ClearContents
End Sub
```

The code is assuming that the end date which complete 12 months will always 25 Dec Year X + 1, where the beginning date is 26 Dec Year X.

The code is using a column helper, which is column V in the active worksheet.
Please tell me if there will be something in column V or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much Karma, excellent way to get the desired result, thank you for your patience, this is exactly what is required. Thanks again for your time.